# Can't install OEM USB driver on my tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to install driver on my windows 7 so I can debug my applications from Eclipse directly on my Android phone. I've followed instructions given here http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html (for Windows 7), but when I hit search it tells me windows can't find the driver at that location. So far I've tried reinstalling everything, installing every possible package on SDK Manager. My Android is 4.2 if that's relevant.

Comment: Which tablet are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been debugging applications under eclipse for several years using different phones, but I did not have to install any USB driver. Windows automatically recognized the phone and installed the appropriate USB driver. I know that the documentation tells that you need to install OEM driver manually, but according to my experiences there is no need for this.